# UpdateView with a model which includes Taggit field

Tags: django, django-taggit

I can create an object from a specific model with the generic class based view `CreateView`, which has a `Taggit` field. I also have a `ModelForm` based in that model. I insert many taggs separated with a comma, without any problem. I also can update it properly from my admin interface.

The problem comes, when I update the model with the generic `UpdateView` which is based in a `ModelForm` of that model. My `Taggit` field appears like that in the textfield:

```
[<TaggedItem: tag1>, <TaggedItem: tag2>, <TaggedItem: tag3>]
```

How can I show it, as the same way as in the admin interface?

which in this case, would be:

```
tag1,tag2,tag3
```

Comment: use the same widget which is used in the admin interface .)

Comment: Thanks, yes, the problem comes when I add a widget to that field at the ModelForm: 'tags' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}). Without that works fine, but the textfield looks odd

Comment: yes, there are some special css rules in the .css file used in admin (and maybe some extra javascript too)

Comment: But how can I add my custom widget without losing the format of the content?